# Get browser download path with javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, path, download

I searched quite a lot for an answer on the web and found nothing.

**Is there a way to get the download path of a browser via Javascript?**

I don't want to set the path myself i just wanna know where my file goes **after been downloaded** by the user.

Comment: This sounds evil and I doubt it would be possible in a cross browser sense.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That is not possible.

Pure browser-JavaScript is not be able to get information about the user's filesystem. The default download path might also contain sensible information, which is risky:

Imagine that one stores his downloads at `C:\CompanyName\RealName\PhoneNumber\Adress\`.

Comment: `C:\Windows\Users\Username\Downloads` would be bad enough.

Comment: So correct me if i'm wrong: i cannot programmatically access any file system folder from the browser. Any filesystem related action (read or save a file) can only be done by the user using <input> or drag and drop interfaces. That's right?

Comment: @SteNonesiste That is correct. There is no cross-browser solution for performing true filesystem-related actions.

Answer (score 13):

Browsers are deliberately isolated from the local filesystem in order to prevent scripting attacks. You cannot get this information.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloads-folder

Usage

```
const downloadsFolder = require('downloads-folder');

console.log(downloadsFolder());
```

Installation

```
$ npm install downloads-folder
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer. the npm module uses `execSync` which is a C extension for Node.   Isn't it for the server side?

Comment: I use it for TestCafe which is typically client-side test script execution. Works great on Windows Chrome, but I'm sure I'll have to make adjustments when I start running it against Mac, and perhaps some adjustments for other browsers too, as that seems the be the general trend across most feature-functions. npm itself just installs it on the server so you'll have the necessary libraries on your machine when you execute the code.

Comment: @SethEden I can confirm this works on mac as well. And my exact use case is also testcafe :-)

Comment: are there no alternatives method other than adding an extra module?

Comment: I get this error: `Module not found: Can't resolve 'registry-js' in '.../node_modules/downloads-folder'`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe wrong answers. You can do it with some IE versions. It is valid in case you use it for intranet web development as development of products/workflow that requires files. It does not work with other browsers (Schrome, Firefox, Safari, AFAIK).

```
<input
type="hidden"
id="steel_that_path"
name="steel_that_path" />


<input type="file"
id="this one you use to upload file"
name="this one you use to upload file"                                              
accept="application/octet-stream"                                                 
onBlur="document.getElementById('steal_that_path').value=this.value;"/>
```