# Get path of downloaded path in asp.net application

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

i want to get the location where file is downloaded and with which name

can i got  location?

How to get location / path where browser download the file in asp .net

or can we get default path where file will be download?

Comment: This is bad and not good in terms of security see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9840961/1059101