# ASP.NET Core (Razor page) - how to download a file in a specific folder (of the client)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Is it possible to download a file (office document) on client machine indicating a specific folder (e.g.: C:\Projects\Documents)?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think so, unless you know the exact filesystem structure of the OS of your consumer, and there is a method to do so. what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get browser download path with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840923/get-browser-download-path-with-javascript)

Comment: In web app it is not possible to save a file locally on a specific location on a client's computer due to `security restrictions`, as far as I know this is true for on all known browsers. With a shared folder or a folder on another machine with a valid path that is accessible from the **IIS** server you can.
if you want answer of simple download file in razor the please let me know

Comment: I don't want to get the download path but I want to "change" it, pointing in a particular client folder . Shared folders are not "solution"

Answer (score -1):

I need to develop a web-application where user can:
- download a document (office document)
- edit/change the document downloaded
- upload the document changed

Comment: Please stop posting a new question as an answer! Edit your original post instead. Just to add, questions with research efforts draw more attention.