# Placing downloaded text file in to folder

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

Using the [fileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#filesaverjs) module on gitHub, I can save a file using the following code:

```
var file = new File([data], "jData" + timestamp + ".txt", {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-16"});
saveAs(file);
```

### The Issue

Over time the archived files look messy in the download folder.  Is there a way to make the text files nest in a single folder?

if i do:

```
 var file = new File([data], "myArchive/jData.txt", {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-16"});
```

Then the saved file is the whole string.  I am a bit new to the fileSaver and I could use some guidance with saving file in to specific folders and directories.

### Solution seeking:

- Is it possible to save the file inside of a folder within the project scope?
- How can I save the file in to an already existing folder?
- When I use *"jData.tx"*(without the timestamp), the file saver will create a copy file.

  > Example: "*jData(2).txt*", "*jData(3).txt*", "*jData(3).txt*" ,etc.
- Is there a way to overwrite the same file each time, instead of creating copies?
- Is there another gitHub repository besides the one I am using that can do what I am asking.

Comment: `"Is it possible to save the file inside of a folder within the project scope?"` => What does this mean? In what sense does "the project's scope" exist on the user's file system?

Comment: `"Is there a way to overwrite the same file each time, instead of creating copies?"` => Are you asking if you can write client-side javascript that will overwrite files on a user's file system? No way.

Comment: first comment re: yes, save it to a folder already specified in my projects' repository.

Comment: second comment re: I'm not sure exactly.  Is it possible to just delete the file each time before creating a new one? It would seem like an overwrite, but it would actually be a delete and replace type thing.

Comment: another workaround i was thinking was to still save to the downloads folder, but make the files store in a folder..

Comment: If this is a node script or an electron app you could do it, but if it’s just running in a browser you cannot alter a user’s file system.

Comment: npm already init'd. I can install a node module, but i don't know how to use it in my javascript file.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a project at, say `/Users/MrEhawk82/Documents/project-repository/`, and in that repository is code for a webpage you wish to  trigger a download that will not go into `/Users/MrEhawk82/Downloads`, but into the project directory. Is this correct?

Comment: If you have installed `file-saver` using NPM, you can either include it in an html page with a script tag `<script src="./node_modules/file-saver/dist/FileSaver.min.js`></script>` or more common is to use a bundler like webpack or parcel which will resolve imported dependencies for you by looking in your `node_modules` directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practise to specify download paths because the information to a specific folder path is real which may pose security threat.

Check out this link
[Get browser download path with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840923/get-browser-download-path-with-javascript/9840961#9840961)

Hope it helps.