# How Can I open windows explorer so I can select which folder to save my file?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have this program where when I click on the `Generate` button, it should work as a "Save As" function and should have the user select which folder they want to save the file in. Currently, the file is automatically defaulting to save in the downloads file, and I tried using Ajax but I had no luck with it.

Here's my .aspx code with the javascript:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" runat="server" Text="Generate &raquo;" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClientClick="generateCSV();" />

<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {                                                                                     
        $(document).on("click", "#<%=btnGenerate.ClientID %>", function () {
            var form = $(this).closest("form");
            form.attr('action', '/MyAccount/GenerateCSV');
            form.submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

My server C# code:

```
public ActionResult GenerateCSV
{
    StringBuilder csvContent = new StringBuilder();
    string fileName = "Testing"
    byte[] csvData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvContent.ToString());
    return File(csvData, "text/csv", fileName);
}
```

The csvContent is where I have my data, and the returned File is what I have right now for saving the file to my downloads.

Comment: Your question is not related to the development environment Visual Studio itself, so I've removed that tag. Hint: Use the little "i" next to the tag to get information about how to use it.

Comment: you can't force a browser to control where it downloads to

Comment: Where file downloads go is users browser setting. You can't mess with my computer, you can't know what folders I have, and you can't say download an .exe file into my program folders. If you could choose where the file downloads on MY computer, then I would never use that browser as it becomes too large of security risk. Some browsers WILL let you specify a path name, and it will appear in the download prompt. However, often it does not, and such files by default go to the downloads folder and you can't change that. And what about Android or ipad systems (their file system is different).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download A File At Different Location Using HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870711/download-a-file-at-different-location-using-html5) OR https://stackoverflow.com/q/9840923/2275490