# How to save recorded video file to my filesystem with Javascript and Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm working on a site where users can make a video from themselves. I'm using Django but I'm not so familiar with advanced JavaScript. I'm using JavasScript code to record the video which is not my code I found it. It works well and downloads the recorded video but I like to save the video to my filesystem instead of download and upload manually or send it to a fileinput with the /documents/videointerview path to save. Also I like to save it to my database if I click to Download button.

**html**

```
<div id="container mx-auto">
    <video id="gum" class="mx-auto w-50 d-flex justify-content-center" autoplay muted></video>
    <video id="recorded" class="mx-auto w-50 d-flex justify-content-center" playsinline loop></video>
      
    <div class="my-5">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="start">Start camera</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="record" disabled>Record</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="play" disabled>Play</button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="download" disabled>Download</button>
    </div>
      
    <div class="m-3">
        <h4 class="text-info">Video Stream Options</h4>
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="echoCancellation">
            <label class="form-check-label text-center" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Echo Cancellation</label>
       </div>
    </div>
      
    <div>
        <span id="errorMsg"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

**js**

```
let mediaRecorder;
let recordedBlobs;

const errorMsgElement = document.querySelector('span#errorMsg');
const recordedVideo = document.querySelector('video#recorded');
const recordButton = document.querySelector('button#record');
const playButton = document.querySelector('button#play');
const downloadButton = document.querySelector('button#download');


recordButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (recordButton.textContent === 'Record') {
    startRecording();
  } else {
    stopRecording();
    recordButton.textContent = 'Record';
    playButton.disabled = false;
    downloadButton.disabled = false;
  }
});


playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  recordedVideo.src = null;
  recordedVideo.srcObject = null;
  recordedVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
  recordedVideo.controls = true;
  recordedVideo.play();
});


downloadButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/mp4'});
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'w3-coder-recorder-test.mp4';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 100);
});

function handleDataAvailable(event) {
  console.log('handleDataAvailable', event);
  if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
    recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
  }
}

async function myvideo() {
    const returnedData= await a;
    console.log(returnedData);
      document.getElementById('wtf').innerHTML = returnedData;
  }

function startRecording() {
  recordedBlobs = [];
  let options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus'};
  try {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder:', e);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `Exception while creating MediaRecorder: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`;
    return;
  }

  console.log('Created MediaRecorder', mediaRecorder, 'with options', options);
  recordButton.textContent = 'Stop Recording';
  playButton.disabled = true;
  downloadButton.disabled = true;
  mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
    console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);
    console.log('Recorded Blobs: ', recordedBlobs);
  };
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.start();
  console.log('MediaRecorder started', mediaRecorder);
}

function stopRecording() {
  mediaRecorder.stop();

  //const baseUrl='/documents/videointerviews/';
  //const fileName =`${baseUrl}${{request.user}}`;
  
  
  
  //globalBlob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/mp4',fileName});
  
  //console.log(globalBlob);
  
  // const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(globalBlob);
  
  //globalBlob.sendToFileSystem().then(response=>{
  //const url = response.url;
  //  return url;
  //}).then(secondaryReponse=>{
  //secondaryReponse.sendUrlToDb
  //})
}

function handleSuccess(stream) {
  recordButton.disabled = false;
  console.log('getUserMedia() got stream:', stream);
  window.stream = stream;

  const gumVideo = document.querySelector('video#gum');
  gumVideo.srcObject = stream;
}

async function init(constraints) {
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    handleSuccess(stream);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('navigator.getUserMedia error:', e);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `navigator.getUserMedia error:${e.toString()}`;
  }
}

document.querySelector('button#start').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const hasEchoCancellation = document.querySelector('#echoCancellation').checked;
  const constraints = {
    audio: {
      echoCancellation: {exact: hasEchoCancellation}
    },
    video: {
      width: 480, height: 320
    }
  };
  console.log('Using media constraints:', constraints);
  await init(constraints);
});
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def video_interview(request, company_uuid, position_id, position_slug):  

    ruser = request.user.id
    position = Position.objects.filter(id=position_id, position_slug=position_slug)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VideoInterviewUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.instance.candidate = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.candidate = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('/mpa/main')
    else:
        form = VideoInterviewUploadForm()
    
context = {
    'form': form,
    'position': position,
}    
    
return render(request, 'myway/video_interview.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class VideoInterviewUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = VideoInterview
    fields = ('description', 'document', 'candidate',)
    
    widgets = {
        'candidate': forms.HiddenInput(),
        'description': forms.HiddenInput(),
        # 'document': forms.FileField(),
        }
    
    labels = {
        'document': 'Interjú',
        }
```

**models.py**

```
class VideoInterview(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.candidate)

    candidate = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name="Leírás")
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/videointerviews', verbose_name="CV")
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Please upload only the code that is part of your problem. No need for commented code or `console.log()`. Where is your python code ??

Comment: "I would like to save the video to my filesystem" : *when* ? What is the action that will trigger the auto upload to your server ?

Comment: Sorry you are right! I haven't provided enough informations. I edited it. I would by thankful if you guys check it again.

Comment: Automatically set the file input to the downloaded video [is impossible in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840923/get-browser-download-path-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not use `VideoInterviewUploadForm` for this. Use javascript [`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)**

Here we will upload to the server using Fetch API.
We also add the CSRF Token

Javascript Code:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
}


async function upload(formData) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("/video-app", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken'),
      },
      body: formData,
    });
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log("Response:", result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}


downloadButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/mp4'});

  // Upload to the server
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("video", new File([blob], 'my-interview.mp4'));
  upload(formData);
  
  // Download for the client
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'w3-coder-recorder-test.mp4';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 100);
});
```

Python code views.py:

```python
@login_required
def video_interview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        interview = request.FILES.get('video')
        if interview is not None:
            VideoInterview.objects.create(
                candidate = request.user,
                document = interview 
            )
            return JsonResponse({'error_code': 0})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'error_code': 1})
    
    return render(request, 'test_app/video_app.html')
```

---

Also, **your code doesn’t work for at least one modern browser.** Tested with Firefox v120.0, I get an error:

```
navigator.getUserMedia error: DOMException: Starting videoinput failed
```

Sources:

- [Django - Requests and responses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/)
- [SO - Get cookie by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name)
- [mdn - File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File)

Comment: Thank you. I think it will work but I get errors in the console and can't figure out why:
First: 
`...:454 POST http://localhost:8000/media/ 404 (Not Found)` 
I tried it with different combinations with `http:localhost:8000/media/` and `/media/` but does not work.

Second:
`Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

I think it is because the fetch problem but not sure.

In my base url I have this line: `] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` and in the settings media and media root are configured.

Comment: You have to adapt the code I provided. For example I used `/video-app` as the URL linked to the view `video_interview`. If you still have issue you can also create another question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you very much it works well now! I didn't use fetch api before and for me it was not clear to use the link to the view and not to the path where I want to save! You made my day!